# How to find the total number of groups from 2 to N + 1

Tags: algorithm

In a particular social network friends are automatically allocated to users by the system and users cannot add friends of their choice on their own. There are currently N users on the social network, labeled from 2 to N + 1. For every i-th user (where i ranges from 2 to N + 1), the system allocated all the users labeled with multiples of i as the user's friends (if possible).
One day, all users of the social network come together for a meeting and form groups such that each person in a group is a direct friend or a friend of friend of every other person of that group.

Example:
input: 10

Output: 3

Explanation:

Three groups will be formed:{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10}, {7} and {11}

Comment: What have you tried, and where do you get stuck?

Comment: I can't figured out how to do the whole task :(. It's for homework

Comment: "*Three groups will be formed:2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10*" -- there aren't 3 groups there

Comment: Sorry.. It is 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11

Comment: Please read [ask], particularly the section on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Is the friend relation bi-directional? Are you looking for the minimal number of groups?

Comment: @ManojBanik If I understand it I could make it without asking a question for help and example.

Comment: @SaiBot I can't answare to your question properly, because the he explanation of my task is entrusted to me and that's why I'm asking audience for help...

Comment: @K.Vodenicharov we are asking you to clarify your question. The current question is unclear the way it is worded. Only after we understand what you are asking we can help you with the answer.

Comment: I would assume the three groups are {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10}, {7} and {11}, but then 8 is a friend of a friend (2) of a friend (6) of 3, so I am not sure

Comment: The array that you have typed I think is correct, but how to implemented, I don't know, because when you input "10" you have to get the output: 3.

Comment: @K.Vodenicharov Unfortunately, if the question fundamentally doesn't make sense, then we won't be able to magically make sense of it. If we can't understand it, and you can't add clarity, then I think your only option is to go back to the person who set the question and ask them for clarification

Comment: @canton7 I think i was clear. When you input number 10 you have to get an output 3. The output 3 is 3 groups which is the array: {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} {7} {11}
When you input number 5 you have to get 2 groups and output 2, which the array is 
{2, 3, 4, 6}. The practical implementation is the hard part for me..

Comment: @K.Vodenicharov Your question says `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 11` not `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} {7} {11}`. Please [edit] your question so that it is correct. People have repeatedly said that `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 11` **does not indicate 3 groups**, and until now you have not clarified.

Comment: @K.Vodenicharov but 8 is not a friend or a friend of a friend of 3, so either your question is still worded incorrectly or the example is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Input**: `10`

**members**: `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}`

**Direct friends**: (*the users labeled with multiples of i as the user's friends*)

```
2 --> {4, 6, 8, 10}
3 --> {6, 9}
4 --> {2, 8}
5 --> {10}
6 --> {2, 3}
7 --> {}
8 --> {2, 4}
9 --> {3}
10 --> {5}
11 --> {}
```

**Friend of friend**: (Union of all the friend of friend's set - Direct friends.)

```
2 --> {3, 5}
```

Explanation:
Direct Friend, `2 --> {4, 6, 8, 10}`

So,

```
{2, 8} U {2, 3} U {2, 4} U {5} - {4, 6, 8, 10}
= {2, 3, 4, 5, 8} - {4, 6, 8, 10}
= {3, 5}
```

[removing 2 itself.]

Similarly,

```
3 --> {2}
4 --> {6, 10}
5 --> {2}
6 --> {4, 8, 9, 10}
7 --> {}
8 --> {6, 10}
9 --> {6}
10 --> {}
11 --> {}
```

**Now grouping**:

Taking the first direct friend group,
`{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}`, now adding every members direct friend or friend of friends

```
={2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10}
```

Removing all of those from the members set, `{7, 11}`

They have no friend, so they form two groups `{7}` and `{11}`

**As a result, we have 3 groups.**

Input: `5`

members: `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`

Direct friends:

```
2 --> {4, 6}
3 --> {6}
4 --> {2}
5 --> {}
6 --> {3}
```

Friend of friend: (Union of all the friend of friend's set - Direct friends.)

```
2 --> {3}
3 --> {2}
4 --> {6}
5 --> {}
6 --> {}
```

Now grouping:

Taking the first direct friend group,

```
{2, 4, 6}, now adding every members direct friend or friend of friends
={2, 3, 4, 6}
```

Removing all of those from the members set, `{5}`

```
As a result, we have 2 groups.
```

**Implementation:**

Java `HashSet` will be a good option to implement it.

I think the explanation is good enough to start with. If you have problem in implementation ask here.

**I've implemented it, here is some sample inputs/outputs:**

```
Input: N = 4
Total Groups: 3
Groups: [[3], [5], [2, 4]]

Input: N = 10
Total Groups: 3
Groups: [[7], [11], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]]

Input: N = 13
Total Groups: 3
Groups: [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14], [11], [13]]

Input: N = 20
Total Groups: 5
Groups: [[17], [19], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21], [11], [13]]
```

Answer (score 5):

All the users will be in the same group except the prime numbers which don't have any multiple less than N+1.
The smallest multiple would be 2*(prime number), so if n+1 < 2*prime_number we will increment the number of groups.
C++ solution ->

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

bool checkPrime(int num)
{
    for(int i=2; i<=sqrt(num); i++)
    {
        if(num%i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int ans = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n + 1; i++)
        if(checkPrime(i) && i * 2 > n + 1) ans++;
    if(n <= 2) ans--;
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is based on the following observation:

```
A user will either be in a group with "2" or be in a group by himself
```

Based on this you can derive that all users `x` where `x > N/2` and `x` is prime will be in a single-user group and all other users will form a group with 2.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2:

```
func friendGroup(input1: Int) -> Int {
var ans = 1
for i in 2...(input1 + 1) {
    if checkPrime(num:i) && (i * 2 > input1 + 1) {
        ans = ans + 1
    }
}
if input1 <= 2 {
    ans = ans - 1
}
return ans
}

func checkPrime(num: Int) -> Bool {
  return num > 1 && !(2..<num).contains{num % $0 == 0}
}
```

Output: 3

Answer (score 0):

The solution is working perfectly but not optimized.

```
package com.demo.datastructure;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class SocialNetwork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
        int value = 0;

        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 2; i <= value + 1; i++) {

            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 1; j * i <= value + 1; j++) {
                int tempValue = j * i;

                list.add(tempValue);

                if (i != tempValue) {
                    List<Integer> addedList = map.get(tempValue);

                    if (addedList == null) {
                        addedList = new ArrayList<>();
                    }

                    if (!addedList.contains(i)) {
                        addedList.add(i);
                        map.put(tempValue, addedList);
                    }
                }
            }

            List<Integer> currList = map.get(i);
            if (currList != null)
                currList.addAll(list);
            else
                currList = list;

            map.put(i, currList);
        }

        // Iterate through all elements of map

        Iterator<Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

        List<Integer> visitedKeys = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Set<Integer>> listSet = new ArrayList<>();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry = iterator.next();
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            List<Integer> keyValue = entry.getValue();

            if (visitedKeys.contains(key)) {
                continue;
            }

            Set<Integer> setItem = new HashSet<>();
            updateSet(key, keyValue, visitedKeys, map, setItem);

            listSet.add(setItem);
        }

        System.out.println("groups=" + listSet);
        System.out.println("Number of groups=" + listSet.size());
    }

    private static void updateSet(Integer key, List<Integer> keyValue, List<Integer> visitedKeys,
            HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map, Set<Integer> setItem) {

        for (Integer item : keyValue) {

            if (visitedKeys.contains(item)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!item.equals(key)) {
                List<Integer> mapVal = map.get(item);
                if (mapVal != null) {
                    updateSet(item, mapVal, visitedKeys, map, setItem);
                }
            }

            visitedKeys.add(item);

            setItem.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Please improve my solution at the below-given link -

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239681/system-generated-social-network

Answer (score 0):

```
package javacourse;

import java.util.*;

public class SocialNetworkGroups {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter total people:");
        int totalPeople = sc.nextInt();
        HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> directFriends = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Set<Integer>> friendsGroups = new HashSet<>();

        int member = 2;
        while (member <= totalPeople+1){
            //member should be added their friends group
            Set<Integer> memberFriends = new HashSet<>();
            memberFriends.add(member);
            for(int i=2;i<=totalPeople+1;i++){
                //check direct friends
                if(i<member && (member % i ==0)){
                    memberFriends.add(i);
                }else if(i%member==0){
                    memberFriends.add(i);
                }
                directFriends.put(member,memberFriends);
            }
            member++;
        }
        System.out.println("Direct Friends:");
       directFriends.keySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e+" --> "+directFriends.get(e).toString()));

       //if direct friends has any common friend - they are of same group otherwise different group
        //initial group with member 2
        Set<Integer> friendsOfFriends = new HashSet<>(directFriends.get(2));
        directFriends.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
            if(friendsOfFriends.stream().anyMatch(e.getValue()::contains)){
                //common friend present for the member so, they are friends of friends
               friendsOfFriends.addAll(e.getValue());
            }else {
                //No common friends, so new group
                friendsGroups.add(e.getValue());
            }
        });
        //finally, add friends of friends group collected when they are common friends present
        friendsGroups.add(friendsOfFriends);
        System.out.println("Friends Groups:");
        friendsGroups.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("Group count: "+friendsGroups.size());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. :)

```
def common(lis1,lis2):
    a=set(lis1)
    b=set(lis2)
    if a&b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

num=20
count=0
a=[]
for x in range(2,num+2):
    a.append(x)
dict1={}
for x in a:
    b=[]
    for y in a:
        if y%x==0:
            b.append(y)
    dict1[x]=b

start=dict1[2]
for x in a:
    if common(start,dict1[x])==False:
        count+=1
    else:
        start+=dict1[x]
print(count+1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### code is failing for some cases

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void dfs(unordered_map<int,vector<int>> &mp,unordered_map<int,int> &ump,int pos){
    
    for(auto i:mp[pos]){
        if(ump[i]!=1){
            ump[i]=1;
            dfs(mp,ump,i);
        }
    }
}

int solve(int n){
unordered_map<int,vector<int>> mp;
unordered_map<int,int> ump;
    for(int i=2;i<=n+1;i++ ){
        
        for(int j=2*i;j<=n+1;j+=i){
            if(mp.find(j)==mp.end()){
                mp[j].push_back(i);
                mp[i].push_back(j);
            }
            else{
                mp[j].push_back(i);
                mp[i].push_back(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n+1;i++){
        if(ump[i]!=1){
            dfs(mp,ump,i);
            ans++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &graph,vector<bool> &visited,int i){
    visited[i]=true;
    for(auto it:graph[i]){
        if(!visited[it]){
            dfs(graph,visited,it);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<int>> graph(n+2);
    for(int i=2;i<=n+1;i++){
        int j=1;
        while(j*i<=n+1){
            graph[i].push_back(j*i);
            graph[j*i].push_back(i);
            j++;
        }
    }
    vector<bool> visited(n+2,false);
    int count=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n+1;i++){
       if(!visited[i]){
           dfs(graph,visited,i);
           count++;
       }
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).